# How to determine direction of polygons (QGIS)

Tags: qgis

In this case the polygons are in the north-north-west direction, would you able to automatically extract this direction?
[image: Polygons]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`main angle()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html?highlight=azimuth#main-angle) returns the value you're looking for, in degree, based on the oriented bbox of your features.

Comment: Just that you can't be sure if its NNW or SSE (like 337.5 vs. 157.5), depending on the orientation

Comment: Yeah, but how do you determine, how a symmetrical geometry is oriented?

Comment: True, more as a reminder to OP that you have to take into consideration both cases.

Comment: @Babel thank you for the comment, but both are fine I just need the axis of orientation. Thank you a lot Erik!